# input dynamic nested list into terraform setproduct() function

Tags: terraform

**Problem:**

I have a dynamic nested list that I want to input into the terraform [setproduct()](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/setproduct.html) function. I can't pass the nested list directly to the setproduct() function nor use a for loop to iterate through the nested list within the setproduct() function (see attempts section). The setproduct() function works only when I explicitly define 2 or more single-level lists arguments (see expected output section).

**Input:** (the sublists are dynamically created which means the sublist index range varies)

```
locals {
    foo = [
        [
            {"honda" = "passport"},
            {"honda" = "civic"}
        ],
        [
            {"toyota" = "prius"}
        ]
    ]
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
bar = [
  [
    {"honda" = "passport"},
    {"toyota" = "prius"}
  ],
  [
    {"honda" = "civic"},
    {"toyota" = "prius"}
  ]
]
```

The expected output can be created using the output block below. Although as stated in the problem section, the local.foo nested list has a dynamic 2nd level index range. So explicitly defining the `[0]` and `[1]` indice isn't a viable solution.

```
output "bar" {
  value = setproduct(local.foo[0], local.foo[1])
}
```

**Attempts:**

**#1**

```
output "bar" {
  value = setproduct(local.foo)
}
```

Output error:

```
on test.tf line 35, in output "attempts":
  35:     value = setproduct(local.foo)
    |----------------
    | local.foo is tuple with 2 elements

Call to function "setproduct" failed: at least two arguments are required.
```

**#2**

```
output "bar" {
  value = setproduct(local.foo[*])
}
```

Output error:

```
on test.tf line 35, in output "attempts":
  35:     value = setproduct(local.foo[*])
    |----------------
    | local.foo is tuple with 2 elements

Call to function "setproduct" failed: at least two arguments are required.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are after [Expanding Function Arguments](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#expanding-function-arguments):

```
output "bar" {
  value = setproduct(local.foo...)
}
```

Comment: Never knew TF DSL had a "splat" style operator until just now.

Comment: @MattSchuchard It can be quite hand :-)

Comment: Of course, we need to watch out for terminology because [Splat operator](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#splat-expressions) already means something else in Terraform. :D